# OOM memory after kernel restart, was working before

Tags: keras, gpu, aws, sagemaker

Ran my CNN on a SageMaker notebook and it started training, but I had to restart the kernel due to AWS disconnecting. However when I tried to rerun my code, I received an OOM error, and it never started training again. I tried:

- Restarting the kernel
- Restarted the AWS machine
  But the error still persisted. I find this strange due to the fact it ran before.

ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[262145,25600] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:RandomUniform]

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to 2 possible reasons:

1. First time you ran the model, it got **loaded into the GPU memory**. When you disconnected and connected again, the was **still loaded** into the memory. When you again ran the notebook, it tried to load the model but could not as there was already a model loaded. If this is the case what you could do is **kill all python PID's** and try again.
2. It may happen sometimes that when the batch size is too big, the **initial few epochs may run properly** but subsequent epochs **may not run** due to OOM error. In this case, you can decrease the batch size and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can decrease the batch size of the data in model.fit.for example if you have set batch size 32 you can change it to 16 ot 8

Comment: I shouldn't need to do this though because it was running before